# javax persistence rollbackException

Tags: java, jpa

I'm new to JPA and I'm trying some basic relationships.

I have two entities

```
 @Entity
@Table(name = "relationshipDepartment")
public class Department implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue()
    private Long id;
    @Version
    @Column(name = "OPTLOCK")
    private long version;
    private String name;
    private String code;
    @OneToOne
    private Employee manager;

    public Department() {
        super();
    }

     getters and setters
```

and

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "relationshipEmployee")
public class Employee implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue()
    private Long id;
    @Version
    @Column(name = "OPTLOCK")
    private long version;
    private String name;
    private String title;
    private double salary;
    @ManyToOne
    private Employee supervisor;
    // A employee is a member of one department
    @ManyToOne
    private Department department;

    public long getVersion() {
        return version;
    }
    getters and setters
```

When I just try to add some entities like this ;

```
   public class Starter {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Employee ceo  = new Employee ();
        Employee manager1 = new Employee ();
        Employee manager2 = new Employee ();

        ceo.setName("Bill Clinton");
        ceo.setTitle("CEO");
        ceo.setSalary(3800.0);
        ceo.setSupervisor(ceo);

        manager1.setName("Hilary Clinton");
        manager1.setTitle("Manager");
        manager1.setSalary(3200.0);
        manager1.setSupervisor(ceo);

        manager2.setName("Tim Reyback");
        manager2.setTitle("Manager");
        manager2.setSalary(3200.0);
        manager2.setSupervisor(ceo);

        Department finance = new Department ();
        Department research = new Department ();

        finance.setCode("FIN");
        finance.setName("Finance");

        research.setCode("RES");
        research.setName("Research");

        ceo.setDepartment(finance);
        manager1.setDepartment(finance);
        manager2.setDepartment(research);

        finance.setManager(manager1);
        research.setManager(manager2);

        addEmployee(manager1);
        addEmployee(manager2);

        addDepartement(finance);
        addDepartement(research);

        System.out.println("All the employees");

        List<Employee> employees = retrieveEmployees();
        for (Employee aEmployee : employees) {
            System.out.println(aEmployee.toString());
        }       

        System.out.println("All the departments");

        List<Department> departments = retrieveDepartments();
        for (Department aDepartment : departments) {
            System.out.println(aDepartment.toString());
        }   
    }


    private static void addEmployee(Employee employee) {
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence
                .createEntityManagerFactory("JPAex4");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        try {
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            em.persist(employee);
            em.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logging.error("erorr at adding a employee"
                    + " :" + e);
        } finally {
            // Close all the connections:
            em.close();
            emf.close();
        }
    }


    private static List<Employee> retrieveEmployees() {
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence
                .createEntityManagerFactory("JPAex4");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        List<Employee> results = null;
        try {
            // Retrieve all the Employee objects from the database:
            TypedQuery<Employee> query = em.createQuery(
                    "SELECT e FROM Employee e", Employee.class);
            // Creation of the Userlist
            results = query.getResultList();
            return results;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logging.error("error at the employeelist"
                    + " :" + e);
        } finally {
            // Close all the connections:
            em.close();
            emf.close();
        }
        return results;
    }

    private static void addDepartement(Department department) {
            EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence
                .createEntityManagerFactory("JPAex4");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        try {
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            em.persist(department);
            em.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logging.error("error department"
                    + " :" + e);
        } finally {
            // Close all the connections:
            em.close();
            emf.close();
        }
    }


    private static List<Department> retrieveDepartments() {

        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence
                .createEntityManagerFactory("JPAex4");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        List<Department> results = null;
        try {
            // Retrieve all the Employee objects from the database:
            TypedQuery<Department> query = em.createQuery(
                    "SELECT e FROM Department e", Department.class);
            // Creation of the Userlist
            results = query.getResultList();
            return results;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logging.error("Error departementlist"
                    + " :" + e);
        } finally {
            // Close all the connections:
            em.close();
            emf.close();
        }
        return results;
    }

}
```

I get a :

:javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction

```
at JPA.starter.Starter.main(Starter.java:52) -> first adding line
```

I don't see anything wrong.  Any suggestions?

Thx all

Comment: Show us the full stack trace of the exception, starting with its exact error message. And re-read your JPA book. An EntityManagerFactory is supposed to create only once. It's a heavyweight, thread-safe object.

Comment: It's just for this simple excercise.  I just don't understand why the rollback.

Comment: Yes. So since it's an exercise, let's do it bad. And why don't you give us the stack trace if you want us to help you understand why the rollback?

Comment: First of all, that's the way my teacher teached it to me.  If you would suggest another (better) way maybe a sugegstion would be better then answering by biting my nose off.  Secondly I'm on this moment not on my home computer so I'm not able to post the full stack trace, but the question on it's own is clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem is that you call persists even for objects that have already been persisted. When you persist manager1 (via addEmployee ()) JPA will also persist finance. So, you cannot persist it again in the addDepartment(). I would recommend to keep only one function for persisting objects and call this function once passing the root object.